# Can anyone tranlsate this for me? year is 1896

Tags: german-to-english

Can anyone translate this please. I'm looking for info reguarding a Friedrich Roloff and his name is here and I am wondering what is being said. I was hoping this was his obituary. Please and thank you to anyone that can help

[image]

Comment: We don't do translation requests here, and this should and will surely be closed. I know it's hard to read for most people, I can transcribe it for you in a comments so you can paste it into a good translator like https://www.deepl.com/translator.

Comment: "Missouri - Auf seiner in der Nähe von Tuque in La Fayette County gelegenen Farm ist Herr Friedrich Roloff aus dem Leben geschieden. Derselbe war im Jahre 1824 zu Braunschweig geboren und im Jahre 1852 nach diesem Lande ausgewandert. Um seinen Tod trauern seine schon einige Jahre kränkliche Gattin und sieben Kinder, nämlich: Frau Anna Oberley (Floristell), Friedrich jr., Eduard (New Florence), Carl (Wright City), Wilh[elm], Otto und Frau Tilde Lohmann (Cappeln)." (The rest are other news related to other people)

Comment: It is in fact his obituary.